We define the sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ by $a_0=0$ and $a_1=K$, where $K$ is an integer. We have $a_{n+2}=K^2 a_{n+1}−a_n$.
I need help proving that $\forall n\in\mathbb N$, $(a_na_{n+1}+1) \;\big\vert\; (a_n^2+a_{n+1}^2)$.
I've been stuck on it for a few days, i've tried induction, strong induction but it led me to nothing.I've tried the minimal charisteristic polynomial but it gives me horrible things with $K$.I've tried to express $a_n^2+a_{n+1}^2=a_n^2(a_na_{n+1}+1)-a_{n+1}(a_n^3-a_{n+1})$
and show that $a_na_{n+1}+1$ divides $a_n^3-a_{n+1}$, nothing seems to work.

title meant to be : We define the sequence $(a_n){n\in\mathbb N}$, $a_0=0, a_1=K$, where $k$ is an integer. We have $a{n+2}=K^2a_{n+1}-a_n$

it gets easier if you write out  in terms of $k$, especially asking what $\frac{a_{n+1}^2 + a_n^2}{a_{n+1}a_n + 1} $  might be. Finally, take my recipe $a_{n+2}^2 - k^2 a_{n+2} a_{n+1} + a_{n+1}^2,$  substitute in $a_{n+2} = k^2 a_{n+1} - a_n,$   carefully cancel everything and write out in terms of $a_{n+1}^2, a_{n+1} a_n, a_n^2 $

thanks it worked perfectely !

Given a constant $\,K\,$ with recursion and definitions
$$ a_{n+2} = K^2a_{n+1} - a_n, \quad b_n := 1 + a_{n+1}a_n,
\quad c_n := a_{n+1}^2 + a_n^2, $$
verify by expansion that
$$ d_n := c_n - K^2b_n = c_{n+1} - K^2b_{n+1} = d_{n+1}. $$
By induction $\,d_n\,$ is constant. Given $\,a_0 = 0, a_1 = K,\,$
verify that $\,d_0 = 0\,$ and $\,d_n = 0\,$ for all $\,n.$
The result is that $\,c_n = K^2b_n\,$
for all $\,n\,$ which immediately implies
$$ (a_na_{n+1}+1) \;\big\vert\; (a_n^2+a_{n+1}^2)$$

wow that's elegant

@traumathized Thanks! Please upvote and accept my answer.

My bad I'm new to this

Let us make a table, calculating things by hand:
$$\newcommand{\f}{\frac} \newcommand{\c}{\cdot} \newcommand{\l}{\left(} \newcommand{\r}{\right)} \newcommand{\s}{\sqrt} \newcommand{\ds}{\displaystyle}\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
n& a_n & a_{n-1}^2+a_n^2 & a_{n-1}a_n+1 \\
\hline 
0 & 0 & & \\
1 & k & k^2 &1 \\
2 & k^3 & k^6+k^2 & k^4+1 \\
3 & k^5-k & k^{10}-k^6+k^2 & k^{8}-k^4+1 \\
4 & k^7-2k^3 & k^{14}-3k^{10}+2k^6+k^2 & k^{12}-3k^{8}+2k^4+1
\end{array}$$
We see that for small $n$ holds $$a_{n-1}^2+a_n^2 =k^2( a_{n-1}a_n+1).\tag1$$
Let us prove that by induction. We want to prove that $(1)$ implies $$a_{n}^2+a_{n+1}^2 =k^2( a_{n}a_{n+1}+1).$$
This equality is equivalent to $$a_{n}^2+(k^2a_{n}-a_{n-1})^2 =k^2( a_{n}(k^2a_{n}-a_{n-1})+1)$$
$$a_{n}^2+k^4a_{n}^2+a_{n-1}^2-2k^2 a_{n}a_{n-1} =k^2( k^2a_{n}^2-a_{n-1}a_n+1)$$
$$a_{n}^2+k^4a_{n}^2+a_{n-1}^2-2k^2 a_{n}a_{n-1} = k^4a_{n}^2-k^2a_{n-1}a_n+k^2$$
$$a_{n}^2+a_{n-1}^2 = k^2a_{n-1}a_n+k^2.$$
This is exactly $(1)$. So we are done!
NOTE. We also can solve a characteristic equation $\lambda^2-k^2\lambda+1=0.$ The solutions are $\ds\lambda=\f{k^2\pm\sqrt{k^4-4}}2.$ I miss the details, but we can get $$a_n=\f{k}{2^n\c\sqrt{k^4-4}}\l \l k^2+\sqrt{k^4-4}\r^n -\l k^2-\sqrt{k^4-4}\r^n\r.$$
This formula is already good enough to count any $a_n$ in Wolfram Alpha for small values of $n$. We can use binomial formula to expand the $n$-th powers, square roots will go away. And actually one can try to get a formula for $a_n$ and prove the problem this way.

in your first displayed table, some items in the right hand column are wrong...some of them should be divided through by $k^4$

@WillJagy Corrected, thanks.
